# CSS 'active' does not work when converting HTML to PHP include

Tags: php, css, navigation, hyperlink, hover

I realize a 'similar' question was asked but the other user is using a much different approach than I am. I am simply trying to include an HTML navigation on my PHP pages for easier modification down the road. When you hover over a button, it is highlighted while the 'active' page is always highlighted. The hover works on both the html and php pages.

When my index page is coded as index.html, the 'active' state works. When i run it as index.php, it does not.

### Header.html

```
  <div class="header_resize">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo"><a href="index"><img src="images/logo.gif" width="234" height="118" border="0" alt="logo" /></a></div>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php"><span>Home Page </span></a></li>         
          <li><a href="portfolio.php"><span>Services</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="portfolio.php"><span>Portfolio</span></a></li>          
          <li><a href="about.php"><span> About Us </span></a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.php" class="active"><span> Contact Us</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### CSS:

```
/*menu*/
.menu { padding:38px 0 0 0; margin:0; width:480px; float:right; }
.menu ul { text-align: left; padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none; border:0; float:right; }
.menu ul li { float:left; margin:0; padding:0 5px; border:0; }
.menu ul li a { float:left; margin:0; padding:12px 0; color:#fff; font:normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration:none; }
.menu ul li a span { padding:12px 9px; background:none; }
.menu ul li a:hover { background: url(../images/r_menu.gif) no-repeat right; }
.menu ul li a:hover span { background:url(../images/l_menu.gif) no-repeat left; }
.menu ul li a.active { background:url(../images/r_menu.gif) no-repeat right; }
.menu ul li a.active span { background:url(../images/l_menu.gif) no-repeat left; }
```

As I mention above, if the link above in header.html are coded as (page.html), the "active hover" works. What gives?

### RESOLUTION

For those interested, thanks to Kirkby's help, I recreated the Header.html file, saved it as PHP and utilized Request_URI functionality. The changes look like:

```
  <div class="header_resize">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo"><a href="index"><img src="images/logo.gif" width="234" height="118" border="0" alt="logo" /></a></div>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index" <?php if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/index") { echo 'class="active"';} ?>><span>Home Page </span></a></li>
          <li><a href="about" <?php if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/about") { echo 'class="active"';} ?>><span> About Us </span></a></li>          
          <li><a href="portfolio" <?php if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/portfolio") { echo 'class="active"';} ?>><span>Services</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="enroll" <?php if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/enroll") { echo 'class="active"';} ?>><span>Enroll</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="contact" <?php if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/contact") { echo 'class="active"';} ?>><span> Contact Us</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you view source in your browser for the working and non-working version and compare what is different?

Comment: the source is the same, it functions when the pages are html and doesn't when coded in PHP. Other than that, EXACT same. I'm thinking it must be a difference in the way PHP recognizes CSS classes

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with it. It is up to the **browser** to link CSS rule-sets (based on their selectors) to HTML elements. They include HTML classes in the calculation if the CSS selector includes one or more class selectors. (There is no such thing as a CSS class).

Comment: Clearly there is a something. If the EXACT same code is included in a php include then it doesn't work. If it is saved as .html it works. The HOVER even works, just not the 'active' page.

Comment: Can you provide a full example? With the complete php file that doesn't work and the complete html file that does?

Comment: @Craig - the length of the page is nearly 1000 lines long. The code above is EXACTLY what I'm using. the html above is inserted into the html page when saved as .html or used as <?php include ('footer.html'); ?> when included in the same spot on the same page.

Comment: shouldn't that be "a:active" (vs. "a.active")?

Comment: @BojanG - perhaps but it functions the same. Don Kirby's answer is true given the include, the 'active' class will always be contact in the include file Whereas before it was 'active' on individual pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you add the `class="active"` to the correct button when you're including an HTML file in a PHP page? From your example, it looks like the HTML header file you're including has the Contact Us button active, and it would be that way for all pages.

You'll either need to have some PHP code in your header to add the `class="active"` to the correct button, or use javascript in the browser to add the class to the correct button for each page. When I write a header in an include file, I usually create a function with a parameter for selecting the current tab in the navigation section. Then I call that function from the appropriate place in the main page.

Comment: Kirby - you are exactly right. With the include, contact is always active regardless of page. Do you have any sample code for projects you have done to accomplish this?

Comment: This only works with Apache servers correct? I'm trying to implement this in my menu and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jeffrey, the PHP manual says that `_SERVER[]` entries vary from server to server: http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php In other words, your server may not include an entry for `'REQUEST_URI'`. Try using the `phpinfo()` function to see what entries are available for you. The `'QUERY_STRING'` entry might be your best bet. However, I find it easiest to put the header HTML in a function and just pass a tab name as a parameter. Then you don't have to mess around with server variables and it's all explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution; it's very easy:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <?php 
    $c=$_GET[c];
    ?>
    <li><a href="index.php?c=inicio.html" <?php if($c=="inicio.html"){ echo 'class="active"';}?>>Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?c=corporativo.html" <?php if($c=="corporativo.html"){ echo 'class="active"';}?>>Corporativo</a> </li>
    <li><a href="index.php?c=diseno.html" <?php if($c=="diseno.html"){ echo 'class="active"';}?>>Diseño</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?c=impresion.html" <?php if($c=="impresion.html"){ echo 'class="active"';}?>>Impresión</a> </li>
</ul>
```

I only read the variable that I used in the include.